# How to create or connect to a localhost database in DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, datagrip

I previously had issues with MySQL on a Linux boot of my computer, and I realized that JetBrains has an SQL IDE for MacOS that I want to use to work on homework for my Database Systems class. The course is based on MySQL and following the steps [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#mysql) was useless.

I am just trying to create a local database to connect to and run various MySQL scripts for homework, but DataGrip will not let me create a database and connect to it. I am just using the defaults for MySQL (name is `@localhost`, driver is MySQL ver. 8.0.15 [latest], host `localhost`, port `3306`, user `root`, password `root`, database , URL `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306`) and every time it says "Connection to @localhost failed. [08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up."

My IDE looks exactly like the picture [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#mysql) and the `test connection` button gives me the same error as above. I tried the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193995/jetbrains-datagrip-cannot-connect-sql-server-without-specify-database) but that seemed to do nothing and I still can't connect to my localhost database.  I can't run `CREATE DATABASE my_database` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464187/creating-new-database-in-datagrip-jetbrains) because I get the error `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused).`

What am I missing or doing wrong? I'm literally just using all of the default settings and nothing is working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DataGrip is the software which connects to the existing server. It cannot run the MySQL server itself. You need to figure out how to run the local MySQL server, and only after you succeed with this, you'll be able to connect to it via DataGrip.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that MySQL is completely separate from DataGrip and requires a separate install and bootup. Once you install it then DataGrip will connect fine

Comment: Ok cool. If you have questions about DataGrip as you are new to it, just drop a line to datagrip[at]jetbrains.com

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has the same problem i had, make sure the driver for mysql configured in datagrip matches server version. I had a server running mysql 5.7 and the driver for mysql 8, therefore the connection was wrong. After change the driver for MySql 5 i was able to succesfully connect